# Class employees

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I am new in Angular and doing code using angular, and i am watching video tutorial.
I have noticed something on my code and i cant understand how it works.

I was wondering if what is the meaning of this code
"employees: Employee[]" on the component.

Here is my model code:

```
export class Employee{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    gender: string;
    phoneNumber: number;
    contactPreference: string;
    dateOfBirth: Date;
    department: string;
    isActive: boolean;
    photoPath: string;
}
```

and Here is my component code:

```
employees: Employee[]=[{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Kennedy',
    gender: 'Male',
    phoneNumber: 123,
    contactPreference: 'Email',
    dateOfBirth: new Date('10/25/2019'),
    department: 'IT',
    isActive: true,
    photoPath: 'http://www.landscapingbydesign.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/img-person-placeholder-300x300.jpg'
},
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: That means `employees`is an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of `Employee` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
employees: Employee[]=[{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Kennedy',
    gender: 'Male',
    phoneNumber: 123,
    contactPreference: 'Email',
    dateOfBirth: new Date('10/25/2019'),
    department: 'IT',
    isActive: true,
    photoPath: 'http://www.landscapingbydesign.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/img-person-placeholder-300x300.jpg'
    },
```

This means the the employee is a class variable. Which is equal to an array which is of type Employee and it is adding an initial value of an object.

As you can see you have a model of Employee. This defines how your object will look like. For example:

Your model defines id: number, name: string;

If you add id as a string. The Ts compiler will give an error. This will help you from future errors. As in plain js this code will work but it will fail in runtime.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`employees` is an array of `Employee`s.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax:

```
name: Type[]
```

Means that you have an array of items which are `Type`s. It's like the Mongoose schema:

```
employees: [Employee]
```

Except it's slightly different syntax - similar to strongly-typed languages like Swift.

It'll throw errors when different types are added. This means that if you tried to do this:

```
data: object[];
data.push("A String");
```

The TypeScript compiler would throw an error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '"A String"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.